# how to find the p value from a histogram

Tags: r

I have a histogram like this

```
myhist <- hist(mtcars$mpg)
multiplier <- myhist$counts / myhist$density
mydensity <- density(mtcars$mpg)
mydensity$y <- mydensity$y * multiplier[1]

plot(myhist)
lines(mydensity)
abline(v=25, col = "black", lwd = 4)
```

I want to know if there is a way to find how significantly 25 **(I showed the 25 with a line )** is in comparison to the distribution. I want to know if someone could tell me how to calculate the p value between 25 in regards to the mean of the hist

Comment: What does "how significantly 25 is" mean?

Comment: @Camille please read my question, I added more info

Comment: So a t-test of whether you have evidence that the mean is different from 25? That's not a question about plotting.

Comment: @camille any test, `t- test` or `Wilcoxon-Mann`  or whatever test, I just cannot figure out how to do it

Comment: @Camille Yes exactly !!! you are brilliant !! I did not put plotting, I just tried to visualize the data so that people can reproduce what I am making.

Comment: I voted to move this question to crossvalidated as it's a statistical problem. Your definition of *significance* (and *p value*) is not clear to me, but I guess what you want to get is `ecdf(mtcars$mpg)(25)` (ie, where 25 lies in given distribution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to carry out one-sample test using `gghistostats` function from `ggstatsplot`. Below I show examples from different statistical analyses.

```r
# parametric
ggstatsplot::gghistostats(data = mtcars,
                          x = mpg,
                          test.value = 22,
                          type = "p")
```

[image]

```r
# non-parametric
ggstatsplot::gghistostats(data = mtcars,
                          x = mpg,
                          test.value = 22,
                          type = "np")
```

[image]

```r
# robust
ggstatsplot::gghistostats(data = mtcars,
                          x = mpg,
                          test.value = 22,
                          type = "r")
```

[image]

```r
# bayes factor
ggstatsplot::gghistostats(data = mtcars,
                          x = mpg,
                          test.value = 22,
                          type = "bf")
```

[image]

Comment: I showed my data above. `min(df) is 17.29992 ` and `max(df) is 22.2238` so you even don't have 25 value. Let's say the p value of 22 in your own data.

Comment: Modified the answer.

Comment: I accepted your answer